# Can a USB hub just be a simple bus?

Tags: usb

I've seen a few schematics of USB hubs and they all seem to have a small ammount of intricacy.    My question is: Can a USB hub just be a bus with 5v provided?

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: A simple way to answer your question is to look at the cheapest possible USB hub avaialble. Does it have an IC? If yes, then it's absolutely required.

Comment: Reading the protocol section it seems that the hubs provide additional protocol handling.  It is not immediately obvious that this is essential but to conform to power and drive standards the electronic fanout and negotiations are required. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hub#Protocol

Comment: No. Despite its name, USB is not a 'bus'. The hub doesn't just connect all of the downstream ports in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can do, yes. **But** it wouldn't be of any use as a USB hub.

You could only connect **one** active device to it at a time, and even that would probably only work as a low-speed device because of all the trace stubs to the other ports.

If you plugged in a second device, it would either simply cause both devices to fail to enumerate, or if you are unlucky (and more likely), cause **damage** to one or both of the devices and possibly the host port.

You could use the other ports for providing power, but if that was the end goal there would be no point wiring the data lines to the other ports. In fact there would be no point connecting it up to the host port at all.

---

**TL;DR**

Don't do that...